# Eslint errors with Replace, Delete, singlequote and quote

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm trying to run my project, but `eslint` is generating some errors, errors that didn't happen some time ago, and if I try to correct them manually, others appear. Some of the messages are:

```
ERROR

[eslint] 
src\components\Funcoes\GestaoUsuario\GestaoUsuario.js
  Line 1:34:    Replace `'react'` with `"react"`
prettier/prettier
      Line 10:1:    `@mui/material/Button` import should occur before import of `../../MDBox`
import/order
  Line 10:20:   Replace `'@mui/material/Button'` with `"@mui/material/Button"`
prettier/prettier
  Line 48:1:    Replace `············</DashboardLayout>),·idU:·0` with `········</DashboardLayout>␍⏎······),␍⏎······idU:·0,`
```

Among other errors, even with these errors the project is running perfectly, how can I make these errors stop appearing or resolve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo need to format your code with eslint, there is a shortcut to do it on VSCode i think it's **Ctrl Shift P**. If you're using another editor just look for how to format code with eslint. Personally, I had these errors while pushing my app to github because of some failing workflows in the repository.